# Chrome Extension "run_at" page close?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

What options do you have when using run_at in your extension manifesto?

I'm ideally looking for a content script to be run when a page from a specified website is closing down. Just so I can save how far the user had scrolled down.

Any idea how I might manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the content script to listen to the `window onbeforeunload` event and add your logic in the callback. This fires when user navigates away from the page. I'm assuming this is what you mean by "closing down".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the peterdotjs answer, you can use the [chrome.tab.onRemoved event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onRemoved)

Comment: How? How would that allow to run some code in the content script context?

Comment: Are you asking that to me?? Please downvote, I can not:)

Comment: I'm asking you - you are supposed to provide an _answer_. This does not provide an answer to the question.